# Ruby on rails app working on http but not on https

Tags: nginx, capistrano, puma

I have a RoR app running in Nginx. I deploy the application to server using capistrano and puma. It works well under this nginx configuration:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/kiui/apps/kiui/shared/tmp/sockets/kiui-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  keepalive_timeout   70;
  server_name kiuiapp.com;

  root /home/kiui/apps/kiui/current/public;
  access_log /home/kiui/apps/kiui/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/kiui/apps/kiui/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
}
```

But I need run the rails app with https to use a Facebook app in it. I created a auto signed ssl certificate following this tutorial [create autosigned ssl certificate](https://www.linuxito.com/seguridad/598-como-crear-un-certificado-ssl-autofirmado-en-dos-simples-pasos) and changed the nginx configuration to that:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/kiui/apps/kiui/shared/tmp/sockets/kiui-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  keepalive_timeout   70;
  server_name kiuiapp.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/kiui.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/kiui.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-MD5;
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;

  root /home/kiui/apps/kiui/current/public;
  access_log /home/kiui/apps/kiui/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/kiui/apps/kiui/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
}
```

It not work! The browser give me `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`error. Someone could help me?

Comment: Why do you have the line `listen 443 ssl` commented out? HTTPS uses the port 443 by default, so if nginx is not listening to that port, browsers will not be able to connect.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a RoR question to me. Perhaps you should remove the tag?

Comment: Sorry @JackBracken, i'm changed configuration and forget uncomment ```listen 443 ssl```code. I remove ruby on rails tag @jvillian. Thanks

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, @BerkhanBerkdemir. I think the problem was the ssl certificate chain. I didn´t create it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/kiui/apps/kiui/shared/tmp/sockets/kiui-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  keepalive_timeout   70;
  server_name kiuiapp.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /root/kiuiapp.com.chain.cer;
  ssl_certificate_key /root/kiuiapp.com.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-MD5;
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;

  root /home/kiui/apps/kiui/current/public;
  access_log /home/kiui/apps/kiui/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/kiui/apps/kiui/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
}
```

I think the problem was the ssl certificate chain. It was not well created.